# Google Apps Script StaticMap setCustomMarkerStyle() doesn't change the marker style

Tags: google-workspace

In Google Apps Script
StaticMap
setCustomMarkerStyle() method doesn't change the marker style:

```
var map = Maps.newStaticMap() .setCustomMarkerStyle("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/2f/Google_2015_logo.svg/640px-Google_2015_logo.svg.png", true)
map.setCustomMarkerStyle("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/2f/Google_2015_logo.svg/640px-Google_2015_logo.svg.png",true)
map.addMarker(42.7048837, 27.8111292)
.setCustomMarkerStyle("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/2f/Google_2015_logo.svg/640px-Google_2015_logo.svg.png", true)
map.setCustomMarkerStyle("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/2f/Google_2015_logo.svg/640px-Google_2015_logo.svg.png", true)

  var image = DriveApp.createFile(map.getBlob());
  Logger.log(image.getUrl());
  Logger.log(image.getDownloadUrl());
  return image.getDownloadUrl();
```

Comment: This doesn't look to be a good fit for Super User. It might be on-topic on [so] or on [webapps.se], but it doesn't include enough details, I think.

Comment: at that time ruben almost closed my account on stackoverflow for NO reason so I posted here

Comment: if you feel it should be on SO feel free to bring it there

Comment: otherwise it's a very nice question, I like it..

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the size (area) of the icon is limited to 4096 pixels^2, which is just 64x64 pixels for square images

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/maps-static/start#CustomIcons

So just use the small icons.